# Getting code error 500 while adding new Service in Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jhipster

I'm developing a Jhipster app and I'm trying to add a new service. This service should return a list of objects "**Request**" (that has an attribute **id** (Long), **content** (String).

I would like to search a **Request** by **content** with a **@PathVariable**.
I am using Spring Framework.

This is RequestResource.java method.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/requests/{content}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Request>> searchForRequest(@PathVariable String content) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Request : {}", content);
        List<Request> requestsFounded = searchService.searchRequests(content);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(requestsFounded));
    }
```

This is SearchService.java method.

```
private RequestRepository requestRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Request> searchRequests(String content){
        log.debug("REST requests to search for requests based on content given input");
        List<Request> result = requestRepository.findAllByContent(content);
        return result;
    }
```

and finally this is the RequestRepository.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public interface RequestRepository extends JpaRepository<Request,Long> {

    List<Request> findAllByContent(String content);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/api/requests/ciao': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.RequestResource.searchForRequest(java.lang.String), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.RequestResource.getRequest(java.lang.Long)}
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:314)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:352)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1160)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:940)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at it.mobimentum.businessrequest.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:36)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:211)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:809)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-06-21 12:05:05.376  WARN 8096 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/api/requests/ciao': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.RequestResource.searchForRequest(java.lang.String), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.RequestResource.getRequest(java.lang.Long)}
```

EDIT 2 this is RequestResource.java:

```
package it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest;

import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed;
import it.mobimentum.businessrequest.domain.Request;

import it.mobimentum.businessrequest.repository.RequestRepository;
import it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.util.HeaderUtil;
import io.github.jhipster.web.util.ResponseUtil;
import it.mobimentum.businessrequest.security.AuthoritiesConstants;
import it.mobimentum.businessrequest.service.SearchService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;

/**
 * REST controller for managing Request.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RequestResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "request";

    private final RequestRepository requestRepository;

    @Inject
    private SearchService searchService;

    public RequestResource(RequestRepository requestRepository) {
        this.requestRepository = requestRepository;
    }

    /**
     * POST  /requests : Create a new request.
     *
     * @param request the request to create
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 201 (Created) and with body the new request, or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the request has already an ID
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PostMapping("/requests")
    @Timed
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.PRESIDENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER, AuthoritiesConstants.VICE_PRESIDENT})
    public ResponseEntity<Request> createRequest(@RequestBody Request request) throws URISyntaxException {
        /**
         * Imposto la data di creazione al momento attuale, specifico, in cui
         * essa viene gestita.
         */
        /*CustomUser customUser = new CustomUser();
        customUser.setUsername(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
        request.setCreationDate(LocalDate.now());
        request.setVisible(true);
        request.setAuthor(customUser);*/
        log.debug("REST request to save Request : {}", request);
        if (request.getId() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert(ENTITY_NAME, "idexists", "A new request cannot already have an ID")).body(null);
        }
        Request result = requestRepository.save(request);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/requests/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * PUT  /requests : Updates an existing request.
     *
     * @param request the request to update
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the updated request,
     * or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the request is not valid,
     * or with status 500 (Internal Server Error) if the request couldn't be updated
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PutMapping("/requests")
    @Timed
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.PRESIDENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.VICE_PRESIDENT})
    public ResponseEntity<Request> updateRequest(@RequestBody Request request) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Request : {}", request);
        if (request.getId() == null) {
            return createRequest(request);
        }
        Request result = requestRepository.save(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, request.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * GET  /requests : get all the requests.
     *
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of requests in body
     */
    @GetMapping("/requests")
    @Timed
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.PRESIDENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER, AuthoritiesConstants.VICE_PRESIDENT})
    public List<Request> getAllRequests() {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Requests");
        return requestRepository.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * GET  /requests/:id : get the "id" request.
     *
     * @param content the content of the request to retrieve
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the request, or with status 404 (Not Found)
     */

    @GetMapping("/search/{content}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<Request>> searchForRequest(@PathVariable String content) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Request : {}", content);
        List<Request> requestsFounded = searchService.searchRequests(content);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(requestsFounded));
    }

    /**
     * GET  /requests/:id : get the "id" request.
     *
     * @param id the id of the request to retrieve
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the request, or with status 404 (Not Found)
     */
    @GetMapping("/requests/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Request> getRequest(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Request : {}", id);
        Request request = requestRepository.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(request));
    }

    /**
     * DELETE  /requests/:id : delete the "id" request.
     *
     * @param id the id of the request to delete
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK)
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/requests/{id}")
    @Timed
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.PRESIDENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.VICE_PRESIDENT})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteRequest(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Request : {}", id);
        requestRepository.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add the server side exception log.

Comment: Added, thanks a lot!

Comment: did you annotate your class with the following :

`@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")`

Comment: yes, I wrote the same code

Comment: I tried, I have the same error stack trace message

Comment: The problem is in the last log line :
`2017-06-21 12:05:05.376  WARN 8096 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/api/requests/ciao': public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.RequestResource.getRequest(java.lang.Long)`

basically you have two methods that can be bound to the url. 
Can you add code for RequestResource.getRequest

Comment: Again the same error... :/

Comment: please put the code for the whole RequestResource class so i can be able to help. or if you can add github repo for the project so i can investigate properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2017-06-21 12:05:05.376  WARN 8096 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/api/requests/ciao': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.RequestResource.searchForRequest(java.lang.String), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity it.mobimentum.businessrequest.web.rest.RequestResource.getRequest(java.lang.Long)}
```

This log means that you have another `GET` method mapped to the uri:
`/requests/{something}` and Spring is not able to detect which method you are trying to call.

You can change the value of the annotation `@GetMapping` on either of the two methods to be different from the other, and then it will work.

Comment: This helped me to solve the first error. Now it gives a null pointer exception. I added RequestResource.java in description. Thank you a lot for your help, I'm solving this problem... I only have to fix that null.

Comment: is `searchService` null? can you comment the exception.
if so, why not use `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`

Comment: I tried with @Autowired but again the same error... The code says that the null comes from `List<Request> result = requestRepository.findAllByContent(content);` inside of SearchService.java.

Comment: I think that the method contained in RequestRepository.java `List<Request> findAllByContent(String content);` could be the problem, but I don't know how it could be fixed

Comment: can you try this,  add the service in you Constructor:

    `public RequestResource(RequestRepository requestRepository,  SearchService searchService) {
        this.requestRepository = requestRepository;
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }`

Comment: As this level, i can not help you further unless as i said you can share the code so i can truly investigate.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I had to create another interface called "RequestRepositoryCustom" and then define the query there. Now I tested and it's working! By the way thank you a lot, you helped me so much! Have a nice day! :)